# PHP Simple HTML DOM parsing to get to elements inside a href

Tags: parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

```
<div>
<a href="link1.html" id="thread_title_198364">text1</a>         
        </div>
<div>
<a href="link2.html" id="thread_title_65433434">text2</a>           
        </div>
<div>
<a href="link3.html" id="thread_title_543843243364">text3</a>           
        </div>
```

hello,

i try to parse links in html code below."thread_title" tag has different numbers.but could not solve it 
thanks

```
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load($input);    
 foreach($html->find('a[id=thread_title_([^\"]*)]') as $link)
   echo $link->outertext . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load($input);    
 foreach($html->find('a[id^=thread_title]') as $link)
   echo $link->outertext . '<br>';
```

Comment: xoops, i edited the answers.please accept if it was the answer !